# Simultaneous Microphone Access on iPhone

Tags: ios, voip, microphone, recording

We were developing a Skype Recorder for Android and got struck in the issue of simultaneous access of microphone by our app and Skype as Android does not allow two apps to access the microphone.

After reading some articles it seems that iPhone allows simultaneous access of microphone by two apps as many apps are available that do recording for Skype.

I want to find out is our assumption is correct that Android does not allow while iPhone does allow simultaneous microphone access?

Please note that on desktop system we were able to record Skype test call as Windows desktop allows shared microphone access.

Please also refer these links:

https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/simultaneous-microphone-access/7805
http://forums.imore.com/ask-question/357513-simultaneous-microphone-access-iphone.html?mn_qa=1#post2704870

Thanking you very much.

Uzair Lakhani

Comment: Yes, (unless this has changes recently) Android doesn't support multiple recording clients. There are a few devices that do, but they do so by using OEM-specific extensions, so it's not something implemented by Google.

Comment: I am more interested in finding about the support for simultaneous microphone access from more than one apps on iPhone. We already have worked on Android and were getting problems. For Desktop our experience was fine. Now we want to make sure that simultaneous access of microphone is possible or not on iPhone. If there is a possibility development can be started. I hope that the question will be more clear now.

Comment: I don't think most people would guess that based on the title and the tags you've chosen.

Comment: Till now I have asked this question on many forums and got mix reply in yes and no due to which I am unable to conclude. That's why I want some link where I can get details that can help me in final conclusion.